# How to save the "awk" command output files into a new directory

Tags: bash, awk, directory

I have a directory "d_files" in which there is a text file with many columns. I applied awk command to split the text file based on the column 16.

I gave the command like following inside directory "d_files":

```
awk 'NR==1{ h=$0 }NR>1{ print (!a[$16]++? h ORS $0 : $0) > substr($16, 1, 15)".txt" }' input_file
```

This gave me all the required files. But I want them to be in a different directory. I tried like following but it didn't work.

```
awk 'NR==1{ h=$0 }NR>1{ print (!a[$16]++? h ORS $0 : $0) ("mkdir split_files")> split_files/substr($16, 1, 15)".txt" }' input_file
```

Comment: Awk is not the shell so `("mkdir split_files")` won't work like that. Other than that, the quoting to the path is not complete: `print ... > "split_files/"substr(...)".txt"`. Or you could just: `mkdir split_files; awk '{print ...}' inputfile > split_files/output`

Comment: As you said I tried this way - mkdir split_files; awk 'NR==1{ h=$0 }NR>1{ print (!a[$16]++? h ORS $0 : $0)}' inputfile > split_files/substr($16, 1, 15)".txt"- This gave me -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: You can't use the `substr` outside of awk.

Comment: Ok. I tried in the first way. it worked. Thank you very much !!

Comment: `print ... > "split_files/"substr(...)".txt"` will only work in some awks as it's relying on undefined behavior per POSIX (unparenthesized right side of output redirection) and it'll also fail for too many open files with some awks due to not closing them. So YMMV without some enhancements...